# Beam/Dataflow read Parquet files and add file name/path to each record

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, parquet

I'm using Apache Beam Python SDK and I'm trying to read data from Parquet files using `apache_beam.io.parquetio`, but I also want to add the filename (or path) to the data since it contains data as well. I went over the suggested pattern [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/patterns/file-processing/#accessing-filenames) and read that Parquetio is similar to fileio but it doesn't seem like it implements the functionality that allows to go over files and add that to the party.

Anyone figured a good way to implement this?

Thanks!

Comment: Which SDK do you use?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanenko - Python!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of files is not tremendous, you can get all the files before you read them through the IO.

```
import glob

filelist = glob.glob('/tmp/*.parquet')
p = beam.Pipeline()

class PairWithFile(beam.DoFn):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self._filename = filename

    def process(self, e):
        yield (self._filename, e)

file_with_records = [
    (p 
     | 'Read %s' % (file) >> beam.io.ReadFromParquet(file)
     | 'Pair %s' % (file) >> beam.ParDo(PairWithFile(file)))
    for file in filelist 
] | beam.Flatten()
```

Then your PCollection looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! The number of files is not huge, but each file is pretty big. Can the files be read in parallel this way (when iterating through the file list)? Isn't there a penalty for using Flatten here?

Comment: Also, this doesn't seem to work - The last item in the filelist is added to all records

Comment: The read is in parallel. File size doesn't matter because reading of file is still done by the IO connector. The list comprehension doesn't do any work. It just builds the shape of the pipeline. All the execution are deferred after the pipeline construction in Beam. Flatten merges multiple PCollection objects into a single logical PCollection. There shouldn't be much penalty there.

Comment: I've edited the original code snippet. The problem with original code is that the deferred execution only takes the last state of filename into consideration inside the lambda of beam.Map(). With the change, filename is encapsulated into the definition of a ParDo so that the filename can be available for the deferred execution.

Comment: Great! Thank you!